# "I see / can see / am seeing an aeroplane / a camel flying"

Tags: difference, tense, modal-verbs

These sentences refer to a real situation:

> A1. I **see** *an aeroplane* flying.
> A2. I **can see** *an aeroplane* flying.
> A3. I **am seeing** *an aeroplane* flying.

These, however, refer to a hallucination:

> B1. I **see** *a camel* flying.
> B2. I **can see** *a camel* flying.
> B3. I **am seeing** *a camel* flying.

My dictionary (*I Garzantini*) says that "to see things" means "avere le allucinazioni" (translation: "to have hallucinations"). Does any of the boldfaced forms mark the difference between a real and a hallucinatory vision, or is any of them better suited to one situation or the other?

Comment: @Carlo: I think the short answer is there are no special syntactic differences dependent on whether "see" is used with a literal or figurative sense. But note that for "unlikely" meanings, such as airborne camels, "see" could also mean *understand how it might be possible*. Also note that by convention, the hallucinatory animals are *flying **pigs***, not camels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*See things* has the idiomatic meaning your dictionary describes only when used in that bare form, without qualification.

> He's seeing things! ... *He's having hallucinations.*
>   In her illness, she saw things. ... *In her illness, she frequently had hallucinations.*
>   BUT
>   I'm seeing things on the mountainside that look like camels. ... *means exactly what it says*

The idiom may be employed in any tense or construction. In progressive form, you will probably encounter it as a gibe or jeer, as in my first example; in simple past or present form, or in a future construction, it is likely to bear a more descriptive sense:

> If you take mescaline you will see things.

Comment: In some contexts, also “seeing stars”.  For example, “He hit me so hard that I saw stars.”  Obviously, “I looked through the telescope and I saw stars” is different.

Answer (score 6):

None of the examples is likely to occur as a spontaneous utterance by a native English speaker, although any of them could occur as a reply to a question or response to a statement.  That is, differently-convoluted prompts will evoke different patterns and elements in a reply.

If speaking spontaneously and mentioning an airplane in the sky, a native speaker is much more likely to say “I see an airplane flying” than to say  “I see an airplane is flying”.  Of course the latter could occur (with some emphasis on *is*) as a response to a statement like “No airplanes are flying”, although “But I see one right there” would be more-plausible dialogue if a flying airplane is visible.

I don't see any relevant language-related distinctions between your A(x) and B(x) cases.

One of the simplest prompts that will cause a person to say “I am seeing a camel is flying” is “Please use the phrases ‘I am seeing’ and ‘camel is flying’ in a sentence.”  But if not directed to use such forms, a native speaker is unlikely to use them, preferring less-clumsy and more-direct forms like “I see” and “camel flying”: *ie* “I see a camel flying” or perhaps more probably,  “I see a flying camel”.

Comment: Or possibly, “I see _that_ a [X] is [Y]ing.”  For example, “I see that a rainstorm is approaching.”